# Accessing the raw post data from an $event

Tags: plugin-development, users, events

My users have an accountBalance field and there's a createInvoice service in my plugin. I'd like to autogenerate an invoice whenever the accountBalance changes (including from the admin cp), while optionally passing in extra invoice info. Is there a way to access the raw post data from the event to check for extra info like invoice skus and descriptions?

In my plugin I have the following code.

```
craft()->on('users.onBeforeSaveUser', function(Event $event)
{
    $userId = $event->params['user']->id;
    $user = craft()->users->getUserById($userId);

    //raw post data is private so these lines are pseudo code
    if ($extraPostData != null)
    {
        $desc = $event->params['_rawPostData']['invoiceDescription'];
        $sku = $event->params['_rawPostData']['invoiceSku'];
    }

    $oldBalance = $user->accountBalance;
    $newBalance = $event->params['user']->accountBalance;
    if ($newBalance != $oldBalance)
    {
        $balanceDelta = $newBalance - $oldBalance;

        //plugin service has defaults if $desc/$sku are empty or null
        craft()->myPlugin->createInvoice($balanceDelta, $userId, $desc, $sku);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, is there a way to disable adjusting the accountBalance user field from the admin cp?

Comment: Not sure I'm following 100%, but could you just pull them from `$_POST`? (or `craft()->request->getPost()`)?

Comment: Derp, yah that works. Didn't think  $_POST would be available from within the event. Time for more coffee. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just grab whatever you need either from `$_POST` or, more preferably, [craft()->request->getPost()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService#getPost-detail).

Comment: ...and if you want to get a specific variable, you can do ```craft()->request->getPost('invoiceSku')```.